# Angular 6 server output in component (component.js)

Tags: angular6

I got the data from the server and assign it to a variable. But when I use it to add to another variable it always gives as - **undefined**. when this variable is displayed in app.html everything will be displayed correctly

{{nodesID}} //all right result = 15

```
component.ts
   nodesID: any; //tried - number and string
   public url = 'http://localhost:8080/nodesID'; // undefined, should be 15

    this.serviceNodes.getCleitnId(Tokenstorageservice.myUsername())
      .subscribe(result => this.nodesID = result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the value to the variable once you get the data from the server.

```
nodesID: any; //tried - number and string
public url = ''; // don't assign the nodesID at this point 

this.serviceNodes.getCleitnId(Tokenstorageservice.myUsername())
  .subscribe(result => {
       this.nodesID = result
       this.url = 'http://localhost:8080' + '/' + this.nodesID; 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I get the result, but the problem is that the result is visible only in this function(), in the other area of the component it is all the same - undefined

Comment: did you try adding this keyword to the URL links this.url

Comment: it's hard to tell what is the issue with this code will you be able to share the full code with me. (only the component class)

Comment: nodesID: any;
  public url = '';
  ngOnInit() {

    this.serviceNodes.findArbreInClient(Tokenstorageservice.myUsername())
      .subscribe(result => {this.nodesID = result;
        this.url = 'http://localhost:8080' + '/' + this.nodesID;
        console.log(this.url); // its work!
      });
   
    console.log(this.url); // - but here undefined
  }

Comment: I want to pass the result of this in another function (in the same component), but outside the bounds of his function he does not see it

Comment: The line console.log(this.url); is executed immediately after the ngOnInit() function call, at that point, it is undefined.
this.url = 'localhost:8080' + '/' + this.nodesID line is executed after that, since it is an asyncronus call. that is why you get undefined at console.log(this.url);

Comment: if you want to use the url anywhere in the application use it after this.serviceNodes.findArbreInClient API call

Comment: Yes you are right! I did not understand the problem correctly, I need  so that I can call the variable in different places of the component (first get the ID and then pass it to another part of the component). Could you throw off a similar example, I could not find. Thanks

Comment: that is, I need to nest inside this.service Nodes.findArbreInClient{.....} ?

Comment: Happened!! I did this before, but apparently there was some kind of syntax error that did not work( Thank you for helping without you I would have thought for a long time